# Socket: premature end of JPEG file

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to send an image file from a server to a client via a socket.  **The socket was previously used to send some strings from the server to the client** (with buffered input/output streams).

The trouble is the image file can't be received properly, with "Premature end of JPEG file" error.

The server first sends the file size to the client, the client then creates a byte[] of that size, and starts to receive the file.

Here are the codes:

Server:

```
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        //Send file size
        dos.writeInt((int) file.length());

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[bis.available()];
        bis.read(fileBytes);
        bis.close();

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        bos.write(fileBytes);
        bos.flush();
```

Client:

```
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        //Receive file size
        int size = dis.readInt();

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[size];

        bis.read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.length);
```

More interestingly, **if I let server sleep for about 2 seconds between sending the file size and writing the byte[], then the image is received properly**.  I wonder if there's some kind of race condition between the server and the client

Comment: You can't use Read/Writers AND Streams. Use one type or the other or your application is bound to get confused.

Comment: Why does your server have `BufferedReader` ? Is there something coming back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely here:

```
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[bis.available()];
```

The method `available` does not return the size of the file. It might return only the size of the input buffer, which is smaller than the size of the file. See the API documentation of the method in `BufferedInputStream`.

Also, `read` in the line below is not guaranteed to read the whole file in one go. It returns the number of bytes that were actually read, which can be less than what you asked for. And in the client code, you are using `read` in the same way, without actually checking if it read all the data.

Comment: Jesper is absolutely right about this.  On the client side, I decided to use a loop to receive, with guard bis.read(buffer)==-1, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please check commons-io with `FileUtils` and `IOUtils`. This should make work a lot easier.

http://commons.apache.org/io/

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to copy a stream in Java is as follows:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // more if you like, but over a network it won't make much difference
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Your code fails to logically match this at several points.

Also available() is not a valid way to determine either a file size or the size of an incoming network transmission - see the Javadoc. It has few if any correct uses and these aren't two of them.